Are "How to use cryptography-program X" on topic?
This example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/90/how-can-i-add-my-picture-to-my-public-key-using-gnupg got already 3 off-topic close-votes.
Should we send such questions to superuser.com, or do we accept them here?

This is most definitely a developer/theorist-level site about implementation-level issues. 
End-users questions asking about using specific applications should be closed as off-topic.

I think these are separate questions. The important one is "Is this on-topic or not?" That question should be asked first without regard to the final destination of the question.
I voted to close the question because it is not about cryptography, but about the use of a tool that happens to be related. (In fact, this could be added to the faq as an example of an off-topic question.)
With respect to closed, off-topic questions, we should approach a superuser mod (via chat on their site, or some other way if necessary) and ask if it might be on-topic for their site ... and if it is, then it can be migrated. See this meta question for an example: we're reaching out to Math to see what they would want from us first, and then that can be used as a reference for future questions (although we'd want their help to keep migration guidelines current).

That one is probably best for superuser.  Note it is closed now.

Yeah, about at the same time I wrote this question.
